# Significance of Bomma Golu

Tags: rituals, practice

Bomma Golu(or Kolu) is a doll display festival celebrated during the festival of Navratri in Southern India. What is the history and significance of such a unique practice (that too only in south India)? Is there any reference to  this practice in our scriptures and Puranas.

[image]